# How can I change label of datasets (MNIST, CIFAR10) from one-hot to multi-hot in Pytorch?

Tags: python, pytorch, dataset, label

I want to change the label of data from one-hot to multi hot.
In other words, I'd like to create target encoding.

For example, In pytorch MNIST datasets

```
(image, label)

([[..],[..],[..]], 6)  -----> ([[..],[..],[..]], [1 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 1])
([[..],[..],[..]], 1)  -----> ([[..],[..],[..]], [1 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 1])
([[..],[..],[..]], 3)  -----> ([[..],[..],[..]], [0 1 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 1])
([[..],[..],[..]], 4)  -----> ([[..],[..],[..]], [1 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 1])
...
```

How Can I convert like this??

Please answer :)
Thank you!

Comment: How do you convert your one-label annotation to a multi-label annotation? An imagine would only have a single class, not multiple classes. Am I missing something?

Comment: What exactly a multi-hot representation would be for a single-digit true-label?